# How do we get Index fields of an Object in Apex?

Tags: apex, metadata, describefieldresult, indexing

I want all the index fields of a particular object in apex. I have searched through the Schema describe but couldn't find a way to identify the field as indexed.

Comment: You can get the external ids ¿Why do you want to know all the index fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in the describe, but you can query the **[`FieldDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm)** via the **`Tooling API`** and it has an `IsIndexed` field.

```
List<FieldDefinition> indexedAccountFields = [
    SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE IsIndexed = true
    AND EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
];
```